# jQuery IE8 radio button problem

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8

I have such kind of strange situation -
there is radio button set:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'include_test', false, true %>
<%= radio_button_tag 'include_test', true %>
```

And I'm trying to get the checked radio button's value - in Chrome and FF it returns 1 value, in IE it returns array with 2 values (`"include_test"=>["false", "true"]`). I have tried different ways to solve that, but always same result in IE.

```
$('input[name=include_test]').val()
```

with

```
$('input[name=include_test]:checked').val()
```

and

```
$('input[name=include_test]:checked').fieldValue()
```

Any solution?

---

Here goes HTML:

```
<input checked="checked" id="include_test_false" name="include_test" type="radio" value="false" />
<input id="include_test_true" name="include_test" type="radio" value="true" />
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML code which the `radio_button_tag` is generating. At face value, there is no reason why your second example using `:checked.val()` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3upr/1/) in IE8, it works fine. This is using your second example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/gPM5L/

I have tested in IE9, and in IE9's IE8 mode, and it looks like it's working. Are you trying to do anything more specific with the value?

Comment: No specific operations were performed, I'm just selecting value with fieldValue().

Comment: Same difference, `.val()` and `.fieldValue()` are different